# Qtableview, add widgets between rows

Tags: qtableview

I have a QTableview (multiple columns, sorting) and would like to add a button that shows additional data below the current row. For the rendering of this additional data I would like to use another widget, that fills up a variable height and spans all the rows.

While I know that I can create delegates for cells, I was wondering if this is possible for rows or whether that would mean that I would have to inherit from a tableview and modify its paint method, which seems to be lot of work for a novice like me.

Answer (score 0):

```
QVariant YourTableModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int32_t role) const
{
  if (!index.isValid()) {
    return QVariant();
  }

  if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole)
  {
    switch (index.column())
    {
    case YOUR_COL:
      double theDouble = getDoubleFromModelSomewhere();
      return QString::number(theDouble, 'f', 3);  // Format shows 3 decimals
    }
  }

  return QVariant();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is not what I am looking for. I am looking to have an one **widget** not custom data. His would mean hat I could draw something myself.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly then I think this is the answer.

```
QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setItemDelegateForRow(int row, QAbstractItemDelegate *delegate);
```

Comment: Yes you need to inherit QItemDelegate... Though QStyledItemDelegate is recommended by Qt. Use the Paint Method to draw whatever you need. Then use the above code.